# Unable to access AWS SimpleDB from VPC enabled Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, amazon-simpledb

I am facing a problem to access SimpleDB database from my VPC enabled Lambda function.

**Below are the things which I have already done for VPC enabled lambda :**

**1.** I have already set up my VPC configuration which includes NAT Gateway setting,Public and Private subnet and also Security Group and also created elastic IP for the same.

**2.** I have already tested my VPC enabled lambda by calling third party API to check internet access to my VPC enabled lambda and it is working fine.

**3.** I have also added SimpleDB permission policies for my VPC enabled Lambda role.

**4.** Also, I checked SimpleDB connection in lambda code without VPC and it is working fine.

But when I am trying to access SimpleDB with VPC enabled, it is resulting into timeout error.

Can anyone please help me out on this ?